# jQuery append li and braces

Tags: jquery, forms, append, smarty

I have a jQuery append that appends a li to a given ul, to add an input type="text" field to a form.

Here's the code :

```js
$("#ajoutAuteur").click(function(event){
$('.flex').append("<li><div id='vo'>Auteur*</div><div id='vb'><input type='text' size='30' name='prenom' value='{$prenom|escape}' placeholder='prénom' /></    div><div id='amb'><input type='text' size='30' name='snom' placeholder='nom' value='{$snom}' /> </div></li>");
return false;
});
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
<li>
<div id="vo">Auteur*</div>
<div id="vb"><input type="text" size="30" name="prenom" value="{$prenom|escape}" placeholder="prénom" /> </div>
<div id="amb"><input type="text" size="30" name="snom" value="{$snom}" placeholder="nom" /> </div>
</li>
<li>
<div id="vo"><button id="ajoutAuteur">ajouter un auteur</button></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that this displays {$snom} in the input field, rather than the placeholder. In need that value="{$snom}", since this is how the previously input data is put un $_SESSION in case the user submits an erroneous form.

I have not clue how to keep that value="{$snom}" and display "nom" in the input field.

Comment: JS works on the client-side, meaning that it has no access to the session variable `$snom` because it is already evaluated/inserted at the server side, thus never passed on to the client. You will probably have to refactor the code, and use AJAX instead.

Comment: Thanks Terry, at the moment the page loads, $snom is not assigned. It gets assigned when the serverside form validator (php) sends $_POST['snom'] back as $_SESSION['snom']. It doesn't seem to me that I need an httprequest to get $snom as that is not assigned anyway. I hope I'm clear.